# Есть ли способ определить возможность использования php_value в .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Некоторые хостинги запрещают использование **php_value** и **php_flag** в **.htaccess**. Существуют ли условные конструкции, которые позволяют указать в **.htaccess** эти директивы таким образом, чтобы в случае запрета на их использование не возникала ошибка?

Например, что-то вроде этого:

```
<IfPHPValueEnabled>
php_value max_input_vars 10000
</IfPHPValueEnabled>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/configuration.changes.php

> Когда PHP используется как модуль Apache вы также можете менять настройки конфигурации, используя директивы в файлах конфигурации Apache (например, `httpd.conf`) и файлах `.htaccess`. Для этого вам необходимы "`AllowOverride Options`" или "`AllowOverride All`" привилегии.

Использовать для PHP 5 в `.htaccess` так

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value max_input_vars 10000
</IfModule>
```

P.S. Определить состояние директива `AllowOverride` Apache из `.htaccess` нельзя.